# How do I inject a custom principal?

Tags: java, authentication, guice, dropwizard, okta

I am using Java 8, Dropwizard, Guice and Okta. How should the injection of the custom principal happen? The following works when called from `Application.initialized` but I am looking for a Guice way:

```
// Bind our custom principal to the @Auth annotation
environment.jersey().register(
    new AuthValueFactoryProvider.Binder<>(AccessTokenPrincipal.class));
```

I tried this module and then bundling it in the app but no luck:

```
public class AuthModule extends AbstractModule {
  @Override
  protected void configure() {
  }

  @Provides
  public AuthValueFactoryProvider.Binder<AccessTokenPrincipal> providesPrincipalBinder() {
    return new AuthValueFactoryProvider.Binder<>(AccessTokenPrincipal.class);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the documentation for [@Provides](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/4.2/javadoc/index.html?com/google/inject/Provides.html): "The method's return type is bound to its returned value". So instead of Providing a Binder, you should provide the AccessTokenPrincipal itself*

*This is done automatically by Guice if you have the AccessTokenPrincipal contructor annotated with @Inject. The ATP constructor has to have all of its dependencies accounted for as well though.

[EDIT] I just looked through AuthValueFactoryProvider. These seems smelly, but want you might need to do is create the Binder (as you do above). Then use #[getProvider](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/index.html?com/google/inject/Binder.html) and then install that provider in a module's configure using `bind(ATP.class).toProvider(new<>AVFP(...).Binder<>(ATP).getProvider())`